# Replace link text in string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using a [twitter fetcher script](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher), but the links are 'unshortened' links mucking up a site design.

The HTML for each feed entry is passed as a string to a callback function. I need to parse the string and replace the link text with the href attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a simpler answer:

```
function replaceLinkText(tweetCode) {
    var parsed = $('<div>' + tweetCode + '</div>');
    $(".tweet > a", parsed).each(function(eli, elel) {
        $(elel).text(elel.href);
    });
    return parsed.html();
}
```

Comment: parsed.html() - undefined is not a function. This is what the jQuery methods were doing when I was trying them. Access the attributes directly is fine.

Comment: I just got rid of the call to `$.parseHTML()`. It returns an array rather than a jQuery object, which I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. Parsing the HTML string in from the callback seems unique to stackoverflow. I spent a while experimenting with using jQuery methods versus accessing the object attributes directly. The 2 nested loops also reduce script portability.

```
function replaceLinkText(tweetCode) {
    var parsed = $.parseHTML(tweetCode);
    var outputString = "";
    $.each(parsed, function(i,el) {
        if (el.className == "tweet") {
            $.each(el.children, function(eli, elel) {
                if (elel.nodeName == 'A' ) {
                    elel.textContent = elel.href;
                }
            });
        }
        outputString += el.outerHTML;
    });

    return outputString;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or part of the question? It seems like you should just be able to use `$(".tweet > a", parsed).each()` to access all the links in the tweet code.

Comment: are you asking a question or answering it?

Comment: `innerText` isn't portable to Firefox, either. `textContent` is the standard property.